# Как сказать системе, что файл изменился, не меняя его?

Tags: linux, unix

Как сказать системе, что файл изменился, не меняя его?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужно использовать команду *touch*. Например, `touch file` создаст `file`, если он не существует, или обновит метки времени, если он существует.

Answer (score 1):

touch <file>
Дата будет датирована текущей.